# How to update text uppercase style for Grid header in wpf C#

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

Need to update grid header text with Uppercase in C# WPF application

Grid header is Like: ItemName
Expected is: ITEMNAME

Please let us know how to do this?

```
<StackPanel>
    <DataGrid 
        x:Name="ItemsList"   AutoGenerateColumns="True"  
        GridLinesVisibility="None"               
        HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        IsReadOnly="True"
        BorderThickness="1"
        BorderBrush="LightGray"
        ColumnWidth="138.5"
        ColumnHeaderStyle="{DynamicResource dataGridHeader}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: How do you go from "ItemName" to "SUBNAME"? And how is your custom ColumnHeaderStyle defined?

Comment: ItemName" to "ITEMNAME. That was mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, you could handle the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event to set the `Header` property of a column to a custom string, e.g.:

```
private void Dg_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    e.Column.Header = e.PropertyName.ToUpper();
}
```

Comment: Not sure why? But this event is not getting fired. Do we need to add it explicitly in XAML?

Comment: Yes; `<DataGrid ... AutoGeneratingColumn="Dg_AutoGeneratingColumn">`

Comment: We are using Caliburn micro architecture(MVVM) so i could not write any events in xaml.cs file. But this way generates an event in xaml file

Comment: Of course you can. Especially since you are using auto-generated columns. The other option would be to define the columns explicitly in your XAML. Setting the header of the column programmatically in the code-behind doesn't break the MVVM pattern in any way whatsoever.

Comment: @Mahesh why you think you cannot do anything xaml.cs in MVVM approach?

Comment: Usually, till now we never wrote any events code in xaml.cs as our client does not prefer. there is no other reason I could say?